# Exception caught by widgets library -- The following StateError was thrown building Builder: Bad state: No element

Tags: flutter, dart, state, flutter-dependencies

[image: 1]

Although I have been researching for 2 days, I have not found the solution to the problem despite comparing the codes. Can you help?

[image: 2]

I get this error when switching to the product add page. I didn't normally get an error like this.